# Contours and convex hull in opencv2 for a thresholded 32 uint image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

I have the following code:

```
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from skimage import data
    from skimage import filter
    from skimage.filter import threshold_otsu

    matplotlib.rcParams['font.size'] = 9

    nomeimg = 'frame1_depth.png'

    i = cv2.imread(nomeimg, -1)
    #conversione da 16 a 32 uint
    img = np.array(i, dtype=np.uint32)
    img *= 65536
    print img.dtype

    #thresholding con il metodo Otsu 
    thresh = threshold_otsu(img)
    binary = img > thresh
    print thresh

    plt.figure(1)
    fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(8, 2.5))
    ax1.imshow(img)
    ax1.set_title('Original')
    ax1.axis('off')

    ax2.hist(img)
    ax2.set_title('Histogram')
    ax2.axvline(x=thresh, color='r', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=2)

    ax3.imshow(binary, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
    ax3.set_title('Thresholded')
    ax3.axis('off')

    plt.figure(2)
    f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 2.5))
    ax.imshow(binary, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
    ax.set_title('Thresholded')
    ax.axis('off')

    plt.show()
```

I have a set of depth images from the XBOX kinect, and so after a data type conversion so that I can use some `opencv` functions which work only with 8 or 32 bit images, I've thresholded the image with the Otsu algorithm and showed the results.

I have obtained a subplot in which I have my original image, the histogram and the thresholded black and white image.  Now I want to work only on this black and white image and I want to save it and compute contours, the convex hull and others geometrical features.  However, it's just thresholded, but with `otsu`.

How can I compute this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to work with [`findContours`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) and other image processing analysis functions in OpenCV with your binary image, you simply need to take `binary` and convert it to `uint8`. Also, make sure you scale your image so that the non-zero values become 255. `uint32` will only work under certain modes, and to avoid any unnecessary headaches in remembering which modes from which functions allow you to do this, just stick with `uint8`

As such, do this:

```
binary = 255*(binary.astype('uint8'))
```

Once you do this conversion, you can then call `findContours`:

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(binary,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

The above is just one way to call it.  I would recommend you look at the documentation for more details, which I've linked above.

---

As another example, if you want to find the convex hull of your thresholded image, which has a bunch of shapes via [`convexHull`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#convexhull), you would need a set of points that represent your contours, which is exactly given by the `contours` output of `cv2.findContours`.  However, the `convexHull` function assumes there is only a **single** object that represents one contour.  If you have multiple objects and thus multiple contors, you'll have to iterate over each contour and store the results.

As such, do something like this:

```
hull = [cv2.convexHull(cnt) for cnt in contours]
```

Each element in `hull` will return the coordinates that compose of the convex hull for each contour.  As such, to access the coordinates of the convex hull for contour `i`, you would do:

```
points = hull[i]
```

---

BTW, here are a couple of great links to get you started with OpenCV's shape analysis functions.  Here's a link that talks about how to use `cv2.findContours` in a more general context:

http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_begin/py_contours_begin.html

Here's another link that talks about OpenCV's other shape analysis functions, such as convex hull, image moments, etc.:

http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_features/py_contour_features.html

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you so much man! in fact, after otsu I had a boolean value as dtype, now I've done the dtype conversion to 32uint again. I've put the find contour function under plt.figure(2) in my code because i want track contour on that plot but in the terminal I have this: uint32
uint32
0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "convert.py", line 41, in <module>
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(binary,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
TypeError: image data type = 6 is not supported
What does it means???? and how is it possible that i've 0 as Otsu?

Comment: @Giulio - Weird... try casting to `uint8`.  It looks like it doesn't like the `uint32` data type.

Comment: @Giulio - My mistake.  It needs to be `uint8`.  It can only be `uint32` under certain cases.  I'll update my post.

Comment: @Giulio - Did what I fix help?

Comment: Yes! you give me a huge hand! even if i don't have great results, maybe i have to apply some filter before find contour...another thing that give me some doubts is 0 as thresholding value...it looks weird and maybe this is the reason about the fact that i don't see the red line that i've call with axvline command on  the histogram..??

Comment: If you can make another question. I believe I've answered this one so I'd love it if you accepted my answer. Click on the checkmark icon underneath the up and down arrows at the top of my post to the left. I'll look at your issue soon. Good luck!

Comment: Hi. I'm back. Can you post the image you're looking at? It's weird to see a threshold of 0

Comment: I would like but I can't because of low reputation or I can't able!

Comment: Put it on a public sharing website like postimg.com and put a link to it in your post.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/5idizm3it/
you're deserving a place in my master degree thesis acknowledgement man!

Comment: as you can see there's a white vertical line corresponding on 0 instead of red but if I change putting x = img for example I obtain a  red vertical line on the extreme left in the thresholded plot!

Comment: @Giulio - Ahahaha Grazie mille.

Comment: @Giulio - You are thresholding the colour image.  It may be prudent to convert to grayscale before doing so... that way you will get unambiguous object and background pixels.  Convert your image to grayscale by doing:   `i = cv2.cvtColor(i, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`.

Comment: mhm I don't know if it depends about that because initially I remember that I've done as you've said now, but I had bad results (or errors) due to the fact that I'm working with depth image, however I will try again and I notice you!

Comment: Hi @rayryeng ! I've solved the 0 value thresholding problem! pratically need to blur for removing noise from the image before to go on and now this is the results:
http://postimg.org/gallery/1dsznnxkq/a702b9b7/
How can I improve the contour? maybe I need an interpolation before to findContour?? Any suggestions? because I think I have no great result at the moment...for what concern to mark the contours whit a green line, for example, I must to use the drawContour function, that's right?? thanks 1000!